# Video Streaming: MPEG-DASH , AWS cloudfront, dash.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront, mpeg-dash

I am creating a video streaming application hosted on AWS. I have got `mp4` which are hosted on AWS S3. To stream video files, I want to transcode `mp4` to `MPEG-DASH` (`mpd`) format and store in a different AWS S3 bucket. I will be AWS cloudfront to stream above transcoded `mpd` files and use [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki) or [videogular](http://www.videogular.com/) to stream on client side.

The problem I am facing is here how to transcode mp4 to mpd.(without using AWS transcoder, bit expensive). I was thinking to leverage AWS Lambda to listen the source S3 bucket and output to a different S3 bucket. But could not find a module to transcode programmatically(to convert it to Lambda function). Has anyone done it yet and would like to give some insight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An mpd file is actually just a text based index file - it contains URLs to the video and audio steams but no media itself.

The media for MPEG DASH is stored in segments, for mp4 in a fragmented mp4 format.

If you want to create fragmented mp4 from mp4 yourself, then there are some tools which you can look at to do this, or even use as part of a batch process.

One example is mp4Dash (https://www.bento4.com/documentation/mp4dash/). You can see examples here on this link to convert a single mp4 file, or to convert multiple bit rate versions of a single file, which is more typical when using DASH for Adaptve Bit Rate Streaming (ABR - allows the client choose the bit rate of the next segment to download depending on the current network conditions):

> Single MP4 input file
>
> ```
> mp4dash video.mp4
> ```
>
> Multi-bitrate set of MP4 files
>
> ```
> mp4dash video_1000.mp4 video_2000.mp4 video_3000.mp4
> ```

Another example is mp4Box: https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/mp4box/dash/

Its worth nothing that there are actually multiple ways to stream DASH in AWS - Elastic Transcode can create MPEG DASH stream which you can stored and stream from S3, you can use cloud front and services like Unified Streaming or Wowza etc. Streaming is complicated so if this is for a high volume important  service it may be worth looking at these and seeing if there is an option or combination which meets your needs without being too expensive.

Comment: Link is missing

Comment: Whoops! Added the link and also another example. This is a usful blog post also: https://bitmovin.com/mp4box-dash-content-generation-x264/